# Styling pandoc HTML -> PDF tables with LaTeX

Tags: pdf, latex, styling, pandoc, pdflatex

I'm generating PDF files from HTML files. I have a `<table>` in the original source file looking like the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>title</div>
      <img></img>
      <div>other stuff</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>title</div>
      <img></img>
      <div>other stuff, perhaps some LaTeX $\alpha$</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    [...]
  [...]
</table>
```

Everything renders great in the final .pdf file with the following command:

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash -V geometry:margin=0.2in -o foo.pdf
```

I'd love to add some styling to it in such a way that

- the table cell contents are centered
- there's more padding between table rows
- table cells have borders around them

Adding CSS to the HTML doesn't seem to make a difference, so I believe it's going to be more about instructing the LaTeX on how to render the final product.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to use a customized Pandoc LaTeX [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555425/