# To make the output of Markdown Pandoc table clearer

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

Markdown Pandoc Table

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Protocol of Treatment
----------------------------------------------------------
PAH is classified into 5 groups. 

Suspect pulmonary hypertension if patients have dyspnea 
unexplained by another clinically evident 
cardiac or pulmonary disorder.

Chest x-ray, 
spirometry, 
ECG, 
transthoracic Doppler ECHO

Confirm the diagnosis by right heart catheterization.

Treat group 1 by giving pulmonary vasodilators 
and, if these are ineffective, considering 
lung transplantation.

Treat groups 2 to 5 by managing the underlying 
disorder, treating symptoms, and 
sometimes other measures.
-----------------------------------------------------------

Table: Protocol of Pulmonary Hypertension.
```

which I convert to a table as described by this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247003/13173)

[image]

Options for clarity

- increase width of cells
- put separating lines between cells
- ?

There does not seem to be any option for this [here](http://pandoc.org/README.html). 
The option `-S` is not the correction one.

**How can you make the output of Markdown Pandoc table clearer?**

Comment: To my understanding, Pandoc's Markdown does not provide facilities to fine-tune the appearance of a table. What you can do is to write the table in LaTeX syntax, and use Pandoc's `-R` option so it gets passed through to the generated LaTeX document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc gives you the option of using [templates](http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates). So maybe you can figure out how to use LaTeX's `\renewcommand` etc. to change the appearance of all tables generated by pandoc.

If you're like me, and are not too much into LaTeX macros, you can use ConTeXt instead of LaTeX where instead of hacking around with `\renewcommand` you can usually do stuff more cleanly (e.g. using `\setupTABLE` in the pandoc template).